# jquery add id to buttons when dynamically adding buttons

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add buttons with jquery this way.  But I also want to add id's for each of the buttons.  Is there a way to add id's to the buttons cancel and submit when using jquery to add the buttons?

```
$('#dialogInput').dialog('option', 'buttons', { 
            'Cancel': function() { 
                $(this).dialog('close');                
            },
            'Submit': function() {              
                submitPay();                                        
            }
        })
```

Comment: Why would you need to set a id for buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to do this but I'd try this:

```
$("#your_dialog_id").append('<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel-button">').button().click(function() { $(this).dialog('close'); })
$("#your_dialog_id").append('<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit-button">').button().click(function() { submitPay(); })
```

Comment: well i dont think so, OP was rather referring to built-in dialog from jquery ui plugin, not a custom tag.